# Laravel Sanctum tokenCan() not working with web routes? How Sanctum Should deal with web routes?

Tags: php, laravel, authorization, laravel-sanctum

I am creating a website in laravel blade and api's for mobile app,
I am using Sanctum and the abilities to check if the user allowed to get in some places,
but the tokenCan() function is not working with the web routes, but working fine with the api routes,
How Could I Solve it, should I use something else for the abilities and keep the Sanctum ??
code in **web.php**

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function () {
    Route::resource('test', testController::class)->middleware('can:admin');
});
```

**guards**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzU2A.jpg

What Laravel says in the Docs!! https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VMxL.jpg

I followed the Laravel Docs 100%  for installing the package
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum

Comment: In your route you are passing two different middlewares on same route like `->middleware('can:admin')` so first remove it and check your sanctum auth is working fine or not.

Comment: authentication is working, but i added  ->middleware('can:admin'); for the authorization which is not working